# Can I suppress Azure Blobs from storing Etag, Modified, and Content Type

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to store over a million small files in blob storage (10 bytes each).

I'd like to save on storage costs and suppress the use of Etag, Modified, and Content type in order to get the most cost savings.

How can I reduce the storage footprint, or otherwise create the smallest blob file possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. These are system properties and can't be suppressed. Even if you don't specify content type, blob storage saves it as application/octet-stream.